# Calculate the value of $f(4)$ given the following conditions (Korean SAT)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

This problem comes from the Korean SAT (수능) last year:

[image]

The translation reads:

22. $f(x)$ is a cubic function with leading coefficient $1$, and $g(x)$ is continuous under real number, and they satisfy the following conditions. Calculate $f(4)$.

- for all real number $x$, $f(x) = f(1) + (x-1)f'(g(x))$
- function $g(x)$ has minimum value of $\frac{5}{2}$
- $f(0) = -3, f(g(1)) = 6 $

**My attempt**

Let $ g(1) = k $ and $ f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx -3 $ from $ f(0) = -3 $

Then,

$$f'(x) = 3x^2 + 2ax + b $$

and from first condition in the list we have

$$\dfrac{f(x) - f(1)}{x-1} = f'(g(x)) $$

We can take limit on both sides:

$$\lim_{x \to 1}\dfrac{f(x) - f(1)}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1} f'(g(x)) $$

The left hand side is just $f'(1)$ while the right hand side can be written

$$  f'( \lim_{x \to 1} g(x)) = f'(g(1))  = f'(k) = f'(1) $$

Because of $g$ is continuous under real. But $k = g(1)$ cannot be $1$ because $g(x)$ has a minimum value of 5/2.

Thus $f(x)$ draws a positive cubic function, and at $(1,f(1))$ and $(k,6)$ it draws two parallel tangent lines, with $ k > 1 $.

Also, $f'(x) $ draws a positive quadratic function with equal values at $x = 1$ and $x = k$. But because quadratic functions are symmetric about its axis, $f'(x)$ is symmetric about $x = -\dfrac{a}{3}$. And from these we can conclude

$$2a = -3(k+1)$$

But here the problem remains quite elusive, because we have three variables $a,b,k$ we only have 2 relations, the other being:

$$f(k) = k^3 + ak^2 + bk -3 = 6 \rightarrow k^3 + ak^2 + bk = 9 $$

One could ask what about

$$f'(k) = f'(1) = 3k^2 + 2ak + b = 3 + 2a + b$$

but unfortunately this relation reduces to identity when combined with $2a = -3(k+1)$ above.

Comment: Does these problems come in SAT?

Comment: How did you get  f$'(g(1))  = f'(1)$?

Comment: @CalvinLin thanks typos have been fixed

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad this is from Korean version of SAT

Comment: @DanielWainfleet because we are taking a limit to the first condition, the LHS is $f'(1)$ and RHS is $f'(g(1))$

Answer (score 2):

> $ f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx -3 $

> $f'(x) = 3x^2 + 2ax + b $

> $\dfrac{f(x) - f(1)}{x-1} = f'(g(x)) $

From above, you can solve $g(x)$

$$\dfrac{x^3 + ax^2 + bx -3 - (a+b-2)}{x-1} = 3g(x)^2 + 2ag(x) + b$$

Note the LHS can be factorized and simplified, after cancel $b$ with RHS, we get

$$x^2+x+1+a(x+1)=3g(x)^2 + 2ag(x)\tag{1}$$

Suppose $g$ attains the minima at $x_0$, where $g(x_0)=\frac52, g'(x_0)=0$, hence (1) gives

$$x_0^2+x_0+1+a(x_0+1)=3\cdot\left(\frac52\right)^2 + 2a\cdot\frac52\tag{2}$$
and
$$2x_0+1+a=0\tag{3}$$

From (2), (3) we get $a=-6$ or $a=-12$. Since  $x_0$ is the minima point, a second derivative test excludes $a=-12$. Hence, $a=-6$, and from (1) we get

$$g(x)=2+\frac{\sqrt{x^2-5x+7}}{\sqrt3}\tag{4}$$

Now you can proceed to solve everything.

Comment: thanks, but the question doesn't say anything about differentiability - it only mentions that it's continuous - of $g(x)$ so I was hesitant to do anything involving differentiation of $g(x)$

Comment: eq.(1) already tells you $g$ is differentiable.